# How to hide a particular date from cupertino datepicker in flutter

Tags: flutter

//String day = 'Monday,Sundays,Fridays';
child: SizedBox(
height: 200,
child: CupertinoDatePicker(
// initialDateTime: _dateTime,
initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
minimumYear: 2020,
maximumYear: 2021,
maximumDate: DateTime.now(),

```
                  onDateTimeChanged: (dateTime){
                    print(dateTime);
                    setState(() {
                      _dateTime = dateTime;
                      print("---------------------${DateFormat('EEEE').format(_dateTime)}");
                      if(day.contains(DateFormat('EEEE').format(_dateTime))){
                        _hasDay = 'true';
                        print('-----------true');
                      }else{
                        _hasDay = 'false';
                        print('-----------false');
                      }
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
```